# Split an object into array of objects based on a condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to split an object into array of objects based on a condition.

```
oldObject = {"Chicago, IL:Myrtle Beach, SC": 0.005340186908091907,
          "Portsmouth, NH:Rock Hill, SC": 0.0063224791225441205, 
          "Columbia, SC:Laconia, NH": 0.006360767389277389, 
          "Council Bluffs, IA:Derry, NH": 0.0016636141225441225}
```

Above is the given sample object. I want to make an array of objects like this,

```
newArray = [{"city":"Chicago", "similarTo":"Myrtle"},
         {"city":"Portsmouth", "similarTo":"Rock Hill"},
         {"city":"Columbia", "similarTo":"Laconia"},
         {"city":"Council Bluffs", "similarTo":"Derry"}]
```

I have been scratching my head with this for a while now. How can I get the above array(newArray)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bunch of code you can try.

1) Iterate over oldObject and get the name of the property.

2) Split that name into an array based on the ":" character, since it separates the cities

3) Go over that new array, splitting it on the "," character (so as not to get the states).

4) Put the values into the newObject, based on whether it's the first or second part of the original property name.

5) Push that newObject, now with items, into a newArray.

Basically, this parses apart the name and does some array splitting to get at the right values. Hope it helps and helps you understand too.

```js
var oldObject = {"Chicago, IL:Myrtle Beach, SC": 0.005340186908091907,
          "Portsmouth, NH:Rock Hill, SC": 0.0063224791225441205, 
          "Columbia, SC:Laconia, NH": 0.006360767389277389, 
          "Council Bluffs, IA:Derry, NH": 0.0016636141225441225};
var newArray = [];

for (object in oldObject) {
  var thisObjectName = object;
  var thisObjectAsArray = thisObjectName.split(':');
  var newObject = {
    'city': '',
    'similar_to': ''
  };
  thisObjectAsArray.forEach(function(element,index,array) {
      var thisObjectNameAsArray = element.split(',');
      var thisObjectNameCity = thisObjectNameAsArray[0];
      if(index===0) {
         newObject.city = thisObjectNameCity;
      } else if(index===1) {
         newObject.similar_to = thisObjectNameCity;
      }
  });
  newArray.push(newObject);
}
console.log(newArray);
```

PS: to test, run the above code and check your Developer Tools console to see the new array output.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot.